# authorization issue in asp.net 2

Tags: asp.net, authorization

in my asp.net web application using vs2005 i have enabled roles and memberships with form based authorization. my problem is i have my styles and javascripts in separate folders and i have put separate web.config files in that to allow all users and roles , its work fine with default page. but it is not working when i am accessing the javascript from other page which is present inside another folder . i hope i am clear 
the directory struct is root -> js(dir),admin(dir),style(dir) accessing page from admin dir causing the authorization problem.

Comment: can you show your web.configs relevant parts?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your comments mr.rubens but i figured it out, it was path problem, the relative path ~ is not working on script tag. i have to get the path from page load event. :-)